# Refreshing a part of page using ajax - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Following is the code of my jsp page. There is a form containing two textareas and one button. It has some ajax code to get the response from servlet **Demo** and print the response inside a textarea without refreshing the page.

```
<form action="Demo">
  <textarea id="txtQuery"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="btnRunQuery" value="Run Query" onClick=""></button>
  <textarea id="txtResults"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnRunQuery").click(function(){
    $.post("Demo",function(result){
      document.getElementById("txtresults").innerHTML=result;
    });
  });
});
<script>
```

Following is the code in the servlet **Demo**.

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
  String query=request.getParameter("txtQuery");
  //The query is processed and the result is stored in a string solution.
  response.getWriter.print(solution);
}
```

After clicking the button. The results are being sent by the servlet to the jsp page but they are not being printed inside the textarea. A new empty page is opening and the results are being displayed there. I am not able to understand the problem in this code. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop prevent default submit action using `e.preventDefault()`

Hope your url is `/Demo`

```
$("#btnRunQuery").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/Demo",null,function(result){
      document.getElementById("txtresults").innerHTML=result;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! The url is "Demo" only. I added e.preventDefault() and its working fine now

Comment: @user3490558, glad to know it works for you now. You are welcome :)